# Sending a message back to the client from server - Netty 4.1.0

Tags: java, netty

I'm fairly new to Netty, and I was wondering if I can send a message back to the client after the server receives one? For example, if my client said to the server "Hey, I'm registered" I'd like the server to say back to the client "Hey, I have you registered!".

My ServerHandler works fine, and is outputting all messages sent via the client.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message back from a handler is really as pointed at out the [`EchoServerHandler`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo/EchoServerHandler.java) example

> ```
> @Override
> public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
>     ctx.write(msg);
> }
> ```

If you need to send your own message back, you need to see if the incoming object `msg` equals "Hey, I'm registered", and then send back the other object

```
// Assuming you set up your pipeline to send and receive string
///    using `StringEncoder`, `StringDecoder`
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if("Hey, I'm registered".equals(msg)) {
        ctx.write("Hey, I have you registered!\n");
    }
}
```